# Embedding images in HTML email

Tags: php, html, image, email

So I've been struggling with this for quite some time and eventually got it to sort of work. On some email clients, this bit of code shows the three images correctly embedded, some attach them as attachments and others just don't show them. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it.

The email is sent with php's `mail()`-function like so: `mail($_POST['email'],'Signature',$body,$header);`

*Also, before anyone shoots me, I know this isn't proper programming practice, but this script is a local script that only we have access to for the simple generation of email signatures. So that's why it's not doing any input validation or cleaning at all.*

```
$header = 'From:webmaster@nobelis.co.za' . "\r\n";
            $header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $header .= 'Content-type:multipart/mixed; boundary="B_3504178637_3566343"' . "\r\n";
            $body = '> This message is in MIME format. Since your mail reader does not understand
this format, some or all of this message may not be legible.

--B_3504178637_3566343
Content-type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="B_3504178637_3589184"


--B_3504178637_3589184
Content-type: text/plain;
    charset="US-ASCII"
Content-transfer-encoding: 7bit


Regards,

details





--B_3504178637_3589184
Content-type: text/html;
    charset="US-ASCII"
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<img src="cid:E3FFCD1F-2201-4790-81B5-5F4F9B82A413" type="image/png" width="51" style="width:51px">
</td>
<td style="text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">
<span style="color: rgb(31, 130, 197); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px;">' . strtoupper($_POST['name']) . '</span><br>
<span style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 13px;">' . strtoupper($_POST['designation']) . '</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<img src="cid:060EED13-21A7-4FF2-BDCE-D5A87BD2165B" type="image/png" width="51" style="width:51px">
</td>
<td style="text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">
<span style="color: rgb(31, 130, 197); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px;">CONTACT ME</span><br>
<span style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px;">T: ' . $_POST['telephone'] . ' | ' . ($_POST['fax'] != "" ? "F: " . $_POST['fax'] : ($_POST['cellphone'] != "" ? "C: " . $_POST['cellphone'] : "F:  086 694 0819")) . '</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 10px; border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<img src="cid:CA0B3207-4728-46DE-8BC7-72723443E97A" type="image/png" width="51" style="width:51px"></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: rgb(31, 130, 197); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px;">company name</span><br>
<span style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px;"><i>address</i></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

--B_3504178637_3589184--


--B_3504178637_3566343
Content-type: image/png; name="E3FFCD1F-2201-4790-81B5-5F4F9B82A413.png"
Content-ID: <E3FFCD1F-2201-4790-81B5-5F4F9B82A413>
Content-disposition: inline;
    filename="E3FFCD1F-2201-4790-81B5-5F4F9B82A413.png"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

//base64 encoded image
--B_3504178637_3566343
Content-type: image/png; name="060EED13-21A7-4FF2-BDCE-D5A87BD2165B.png"
Content-ID: <060EED13-21A7-4FF2-BDCE-D5A87BD2165B>
Content-disposition: inline;
    filename="060EED13-21A7-4FF2-BDCE-D5A87BD2165B.png"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64


//base64 encoded image
--B_3504178637_3566343
Content-type: image/png; name="CA0B3207-4728-46DE-8BC7-72723443E97A.png"
Content-ID: <CA0B3207-4728-46DE-8BC7-72723443E97A>
Content-disposition: inline;
    filename="CA0B3207-4728-46DE-8BC7-72723443E97A.png"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64


//base64 encoded image
--B_3504178637_3566343--' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) class instead of mail() function. it's vary easy and powerful

Answer (score 0):

You should use multipart/related instead of multipart/mixed for the main message Content-type.